# Steps in Quantizing Electromagnetic Field for the Gauge Condition $A_0=0$

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge

While reading section 9.3 of *QFT An Integrated Approach* by Fradkin, it is shown (see equations $(9.49)$ and $(9.54)$ of the book)
$$B_{j}(\boldsymbol{x})^{2}=\boldsymbol{p}^{2} A_{j}^{T}(\boldsymbol{p}) A_{j}^{T}(-\boldsymbol{p})$$
The transverse part $A_{j}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is obtained (I think by Helmholtz decomposition) from
$$A_{j}(\boldsymbol{x})=A_{j}^{L}(\boldsymbol{x})+A_{j}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})=\int \frac{d^{3} p}{(2 \pi)^{3}}\left(A_{j}^{L}(\boldsymbol{p})+A_{j}^{T}(\boldsymbol{p})\right) e^{i \boldsymbol{p} \cdot \boldsymbol{x}}\tag{9.51}$$
which statisfies
$$\nabla_{j} A_{j}^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})=0, \quad A_{j}^{L}(\boldsymbol{x})=\nabla_{j} \phi(\boldsymbol{x})\tag{9.52}$$
I wonder how this result follows.

Comment: Just compute the imaginary part of that expression in the usual way.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You're right, I totally missed it...